# Executing dynamic HTML from a string variable in C#

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Data is a string representing youtube embedded code and is read from my database. An example of such string is:

```
<iframe width="425" height="349" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/Ki5GNq_3qT8" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

In my controller code I have something like below:

```
// the parameter embed contains the youtube code
public ActionResult Index(string embed)
{
    ViewBag.Embed = embed;
    return View();
}
```

My question is how do I write the Razor code that will inject the embedded HTML code into my view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<iframe width="425" height="349" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/@ViewBag.Embed" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

You might want to also make sure the code is html encoded.

Comment: Pleae clarify, I am fairly new to ASP.NET-MVC. If I write the code straight up into my view it works perfectly. But I need it to be dynamic because the data is coming from my database.

Answer (score 1):

You need to render as a HTML string. Try this in your view:

```
<body>
    @(new HtmlString((String)ViewBag.Embed))
</body>
```

Hope this helps :)

**EDIT**

If you're trying to render the entire string go with this, if it's just part of it then the answer by ek_ny is the way to go.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to render the whole string. But your solution didn't work. Am missing something?

Comment: Try @Html.Raw((String)ViewBag.Embed). If that works Ill update the answer.

Comment: No error. But the flash player didn't appear as would be expected. If I write the youtube code straight up into the view it works.

Comment: It didn't work. Below is the view code, please let me know if I'm doing anything stupid.
@{ ViewBag.Title = "Testing"; }

@Html.Raw((String)ViewBag.Embed)

Comment: Looks like your workflow is off. Are you actually getting the string? Put a debug line in your controller when you assign "Embed" and make sure you actually have the value.

Answer (score 0):

Try razor syntax:

```
@: @ViewBag.Embed
```

Or

```
@Html.Raw(ViewBag.Embed)
```